# "Stable identifer required" error during companion object import

Tags: scala

I'm really new to Scala, and I've come across an error I am unable to solve by myself or through internet searches.

I have a Scala class called "GUI" that represents a JFrame along with a companion class. When I try to import the companion class using `import GUI._` I get the error "stable identifier required, but GUI.this.GUI() found".

I made an empty class and companion object and the import worked fine, so I assume that the error is related to something specific to my code. Below is the code in question:

```
object GUI {

   def test:Integer = 1
}

class GUI extends JFrame{

import GUI._
val ICON_LOCATION:File = new File("Images/iMovies.ico");
val ICON:BufferedImage = Ootil.createImage("iMovies.png");
val TITLE:String = "iVideos";
val LICENSE_NAME:String = "OpenBSD";

def GUI(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    createGUI();

    pack();
    setSize(100,100);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

def versionMajor: Integer = 1
def versionMinor: Integer = 0
def versionRevision: Integer = 0
def versionPreReleaseID: String = "alpha"
def versionBuildNumber: String = "1b"

private def createGUI():Unit = {
        val panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

def getIcon():BufferedImage = ICON

def getProgramTitle():String = TITLE

def getConfigOptions():LookAndFeelConfigurationOptions = GUIConfigOptions.CONFIG_OPTIONS;
}
```

Comment: As a side note (not really related to your question), the scala.swing package makes using Swing *so* much nicer.  As long as you're introducing yourself to the language, you should really take a look at it.

Comment: As another side note: constants in Scala are usually WrittenLikeThis, instead of the Java ALL_CAPS_CONVENTION.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to Kipton's answer, there's nothing wrong with doing:

```
class GUI{
  def GUI() {
    println("something")
  }
}
```

But the result won't be a constructor -- it will be an ordinary method.

`val a = new GUI()` won't print anything, but calling `a.GUI()` will.

This is why you didn't get an error message about defining your constructor incorrectly.

---

When you run the command `import GUI._`, Scala needs `GUI` to always evaluate to the same object. This is only the case when `GUI` is an `object`, a `package`, or a `val`.

In your code, `import GUI._` referred to the method `GUI` that you defined, because the `GUI` method is defined in a closer scope than `object GUI` (the fact that the compiler hasn't encountered the definition of `def GUI` yet doesn't make a difference).

Since `import GUI._` referred to the method `GUI`, which is not a `val`, `object`, or `package`,  you got the error message about `GUI` not being a stable identifier.

Comment: Thanks for not only fixing my problem, but giving a clear explanation for why it was wrong and why I didn't have errors elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the Scala community.

Scala constructors work differently than they do in Java. To fix the error, you should put the body of your previously defined `GUI()` method directly into the class definition, like so,

```
class GUI extends JFrame{
  import GUI._
  val ICON_LOCATION:File = new File("Images/iMovies.ico");
  val ICON:BufferedImage = Ootil.createImage("iMovies.png");
  val TITLE:String = "iVideos";
  val LICENSE_NAME:String = "OpenBSD";

  // ** stuff that used to be in method GUI() goes below **
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  createGUI();
  pack();
  setSize(100,100);
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  setVisible(true);
  ...
}
```

It takes a little getting used to, but I think you'll find that Scala's way is a lot nicer.

If you want to define an auxiliary constructor, declare a method `def this(...) { ... }` whose first expression is a call to the primary constructor (in this case just `this()`, since it doesn't take parameters).

If you want to add parameters to your primary constructor, you would define the class as

```
class GUI( << some parameters >> ) extends JFrame { ... }
```

and then you can use the parameters anywhere in this class body.

Comment: Doesn't the auxiliary constructor have to be `def this(some params) = this (some other params)`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to provide more information.